# Не могу открыть урл контейнера при запуске его из Remote Docker-Compose среды (Pycharm)

Tags: docker, pycharm, macos, docker-compose, odoo

Не открывается url werkzeug сервера "localhost:8069" при запуске контейнера из Remote Docker-Compose среды (Pycharm)

При стандартном старте из терминала `docker-compose up` все работает корректно.

Выкладываю docker-compose.yml файл

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    image: odoo:14.0
    platform: linux/amd64
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    environment:
      - HOST=db
      - USER=odoo
      - PASSWORD=odoo
    tty: true
    volumes:
        - ./addons:/mnt/addons
        - ./config:/mnt/odoo
        - ./extra:/mnt/extra-addons
    networks:
      - default
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
      - 5432:5433
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
    networks:
      - default
```

**Вывод консоли pycharm:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Отображение контейнеров из docker desktop**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Складывается ощущение что адрес блокируется системой